# Segmentation fault while accessing an object inside a vector of object

Tags: c++

I am having a segmentation  fault while trying to access an object stored inside a vector. I have a Survey which consists of Processes. Each process consists of questions. So the Survey Object contains a vector or Processes and each process object contains a vector of questions. The class definitions are as follows:

```
class Survey {
private:
...
vector <Process> survey_processes;
....
public:
......
vector<Process> getSurveyProcesses()
{ return survey_processes;  }
void addProcessObj(Process obj)
{ survey_processes.push_back(obj);}
.....
};

class Process
 { 
private:
....
vector<Question> proc_questions;
....
public:
...
vector<Question> getProcessQuestions()
{ return proc_questions;}
void addQuestionObj(Question obj)
{ proc_questions.push_back(obj); }
.....
};
class Question {
private:

int quesnum;
int answer;
...
public:
Question (int c_ques, int c_ans)
{
quesnum = c_ques;
answer = c_ans;
}
int getQuestionID()
{
    return quesnum;
} 
int getAnswer()
{
    return answer;
}
...
};
```

As the new process object is created, I store it in the vector of Processes and for each Process Object, I push the Question Object in the vector of Questions. For the survey Object, I want to get each Process from the Process Vector and for each Process Object, get each question object and print it.

I can access the Process Objects and print them successfully by using following code.

```
cout << ((survey_obj.getSurveyProcesses()).back()).getProcessID() << endl;
```

When I try to extract the question object from inside the Process vector, it gives me a segmentation error. I believe I am making some syntax error while trying to access the object.  How do I access the question Object embedded inside a vector of Questions for a given Process Object which is inside a vector of process objects for a given survey object?

Here is the relevant part of the code where the segmentation fault occurs.

```
int procnum = 0;
for (unsigned i = 11; i < all_words.size()-1; ++i)

{   

vector<string> v;
string s = all_words.at(i);
stringstream ques_stream(s);

int ques_num;
ques_stream >> ques_num;
ques_stream.ignore();   

// if process object already exists, do nothing. Otherwise create a new process object and add it to the survey object  
if (procnum == ques_num)
    ;
else    
{   
Process proc_obj(ques_num);
survey_obj.addProcessObj(proc_obj);
procnum = ques_num;

}

string ques_strng;  
ques_stream >> ques_strng;
ques_stream.ignore();
Question ques_obj(ques_strng);

// objective: put the new question object in the question vector of the last process object from the process vector of the survey object
cout << ((survey_obj.getSurveyProcesses()).back()).getProcessID() << endl;
Process current_proc_obj = (survey_obj.getSurveyProcesses()).back();
cout << " Current Process : " << current_proc_obj.getProcessID() << endl;
Question current_question_obj = (current_proc_obj.getProcessQuestions()).back();


((survey_obj.getSurveyProcesses()).back()).addQuestionObj(ques_obj);    

**// this is where the segmentation fault occurs when i try to get the last object from process vector of the survey and for that object get the last element of the question vector. print the question id of this question object     
cout << " Current Question : " << ((((survey_obj.getSurveyProcesses()).back()).getProcessQuestions()).back()).getQuestionID() << endl;**

cout << " Current Process Question : " << ((current_proc_obj.getProcessQuestions()).back()).getQuestionID() << endl;

}
```

I tried running the gdb debugger but it only tells me that error occurs while trying to access the questionID. I still do not know what i am doing wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's the code for `Question::getProcessID`?

Comment: there is no ProcessID variable in the class Question. A Process has question objects in it, but a Question object does not store which Process Object it belongs to. So far I do not see a reason for Question to contains it, however if I am missing something, it can be added.

Comment: Sorry, I meant getQuestionID - so we can evaluate whether it is the vector access or that function call itself that is causing the crash.

Comment: Is returning everything by value intentional here?

Comment: yes the returning by values is intentional as the answer to the question depends upon the answer value chosen by the user. (1,1) means user chose option 1 for question 1 and (1,2) means that user chose option 2 for question 1

Comment: Here is the code for the class question

class Question {
private:

int quesnum;
int answer;
Question (int c_ques, int c_ans)
{
 quesnum = c_ques;
 answer = c_ans;
}
int getQuestionID()
{
 return quesnum;
} 
};

I believe it is the function call that causes the error. The gdb states that return questionID is where the problem occurs. My gut tells me that for some reason the Question vector for every Process does not get any questions in it.

Comment: I have added the definition of class question to the main question for ease of reading.

Comment: Could you please remove all the `...` and just provide something that others can copy&paste to reproduce the problem? As small as possible. If you have a hard time extracting that part, your code probably needs refactoring anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
((survey_obj.getSurveyProcesses()).back()).addQuestionObj(ques_obj);
             _______________copy^, _copy^ -               ^_______added to copy
```

Since you are returning vectors by value, not reference, you are adding `ques_obj` to a temporary local `vector`, not the one held by `survey_obj`.

The crash is occurring because you're accessing past the end of the (empty) vector, since nothing got added to it.

One way to fix this is to return the class member `vector` by *reference*, instead of by *value*.  (Since *by value* can be though of as *a copy of the variable*.)

```
class Survey {
private:
vector <Process> survey_processes;
public:
vector<Process>& getSurveyProcesses()//<--ampersand indicates return by reference 
{ return survey_processes;  }
};
```

Now, when you try this:

```
((survey_obj.getSurveyProcesses()).back()).addQuestionObj(ques_obj);
                          ______^ this is the vector inside the Survey class,
                                  not a copy
```

Fortunately, [std::vector::back also returns by reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/back/), so the `ques_obj` gets added to the object held by the vector, held by the `Survey` object - no local, temporary copies involved!  Later, when you go to query that question, you'll find it in the place you expected it.

Two final notes: 1) You should decide whether you should also return the process_questions by reference; 2) If you had used the ability for `vector` to tell you how many elements it contains, instead of just assuming that `back()` would work, you would have found this problem earlier. :)

Comment: Thanks tmpearce. I understand that difference now. How do i return the refernce to a vector?. I know how to pass reference to a vector in a function. it goes like this

void function1(vector<int> &v);

but the following declaration gives me an error
 
class Survey {
private:
vector <Process> survey_processes;
Public:
vector<Process> getSurveyProcesses()
{
 return &survey_processes; 
}
};

Comment: In the example you just gave, you're returning the *address* of the vector (i.e. a pointer to it).  To *return by reference*, use a slightly different syntax: `std::vector<Process>& getSurveyProcesses(){return survey_processes;}`

Comment: Edited my answer to also answer the follow-up

Comment: THANK YOU so much tmpearce ... Now its working correctly. I know I am not using the correct abilities of vectors, but I just started C++ so I am not quite familiar with the capabilities and I chose C++ for precisely this reason hoping I would learn things. 

Now that I have the correct data inside the vector, I can start writing code to get the answers. I hope I can ask you questions further if I get into any road blocks. Thanks again bro You ROCK !!!